# Discord Python Bot - Automatically remove old messages

Tags: python, discord, message

I am trying to create a python script that actively removes messages as new ones comes in Discord text channel:

```
    @bot.listen()
    async def on_message(message):
        channel = message.channel.id
        if channel == 768046419935363102 :
            with open("polina_logs.txt", "r+") as text_file:
                lines = text_file.readlines()
                if len(lines) >= 10:
                    t = int(lines.pop(0).strip("\n"))
                    guild = bot.get_guild(message.guild.id)
                    channel = guild.get_channel(channel)
                    message = await channel.fetch_message(t)
                    await message.delete()
                lines.append(str(message.id) + "\n")
                text_file.seek(0)
                text_file.truncate()
                text_file.writelines(lines)
                return
```

This does not work: After deleting first line "0", the rest of the message does not automatically fill in to replace line "0".

Comment: better open file only for reading, read all data and close it, next open only for writing, write all data and close it

Comment: you could read it only once - on_ready or even before starting bot - and later you would have to only update list in memory and save new list.

Comment: you don't have to strip `\n` - `int()` will work also with spaces, `\t` and `\n`  - `int(" \n \t 123 \t \n")`

Comment: did you check if `len(lines) > 10` ? Do you want to remove more lines? Then you need `while` instead of `if`